# CPU and windows

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-registers

Can windows run in lower protection ring? If so what needs to be done? I need way faster and more real time execution so I see that this is important.

I know that this can result in system instability (BSOD screens) but that is just the way if one needs way faster processing and low latency in simulation programs that run under windows.

My old PC was unlocked for this. It had tremendous execution speed. I think that windows password recovery that I did because of the password mistype forced processor and windows to execute way faster. Difference in processing of video and simulations was tremendous. That is why this bothers me.. windows caps the underlying hardware for the reason of security and let it run in the least privileged ring. After reformat of that old PC I lost those performance. 
And now I see that my simulations on any other PC can't run properly even I tried on very expensive and strong machines. Windows don't let them! Processing is very poor and cannot be compared with what I had on the old PC.

Answer (score 0):

It override and escalate the privliges. It might have been some form of the rootkit that unlocked hidden API-s and features. Difference is dramatic. I know that rootkits are mostly evil but this was for good thing. It executed my application way faster it cannot be compared. Please help.

I found this link:  https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Kallenberg-Extreme-Privilege-Escalation-On-Windows8-UEFI-Systems-WP.pdf
By the way my PC has windows 8 UEFI.